# how to collect jmeter runtime measurements and create a graph

Tags: jmeter

I'm looking for a way to run a jmeter from command line, 
collect the data from Summary Report to some file (say every x seconds) during the execution. 
Then load the saved file to the jmeter to see the limeline graphs of the collected metrics.

How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way automate getting a graph from results is to use a shell script coupled with the '[JMeterPluginsCMD](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD)' plugin that allows you to create a graph image from the command line.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /where/jmeter/is/installed

# Run Test
./jmeter.sh -n -t /path/to/mytest.jmx -l /directory/to/store/results.jtl

# Generate PNG File using plugin
java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-png test.png --input-jtl /directory/to/store/results.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime --width 800 --height 600
```

To litterally read data from the Summary Report would take a lot more work but I imagine you could do something with awk, however I suspect that this method is not explicitly required and that reading the jtl file (after the test has completed) would work.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is already answered question I'll offer an alternative to .png image and that is .html page. Please take a look at this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191109/169277